# App Store on iPad 2 keeps asking for AppleID password when attempting to update apps

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I have an iPhone 6 which never asks me for a password when updating apps, but my iPad 2 asks me for a password on **every single app update** if I want update apps individually even though I have the same restrictions settings on both devices (installing and deleting apps is allowed). Both are running iOS 9.3.2.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What password is it asking for? A restrictions password, your device passcode, or your iTunes password? (Please reply `@JohnRamos`.)

Comment: @JohnRamos It's asking for my iTunes password.

Comment: @alimbada do you have any special settings on (like parental control "restrictions" or two-factor authentication on your iTunes/iCloud account)?

Comment: Yes, I have recently enabled 2FA on my iCloud account, but this issue predates that. I have no parental controls.

Comment: I don't know what to say. It might be because the iPad 2 is less secure (being older and thus lacking a secure enclave)?

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that you've opted to "require always" at some point. To undo it, do the following:

1. Launch the Settings app on your iPhone or iPad.
2. Tap on General.
3. Tap on Restrictions.
4. Tap on Require Password under the Allowed Content section.
5. Tap on 15 minutes (yours is likely set to Immediately).

OR

1. Click Settings.
2. Click Touch ID & Passcode (May be named something else if you don't have touch ID).
3. About 75% down the right column should be "Require Passcode" with an option to change between Immediately or not. If you have Touch ID enabled, you may only get the one choice.

[Source](http://www.imore.com/how-change-your-itunes-password-interval-parental-controls-your-iphone-or-ipad)

Comment: It's already set to `Require After 15 Minutes`. The odd thing is this setting doesn't even exist on my iPhone and my iPhone never asks for a password.

Comment: I'm editing my answer to have a part 2 you can try. :)

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either. I changed it to 1 minute but I still keep getting the Apple ID password prompt. Also, that setting modifies the behaviour of the lock screen so that it won't ask for the passcode if you try to unlock the device within the specified time window.